# Best way to log non fatal error on Android to Firebase / Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, logging, crashlytics

I know that its possible to record a non fatal `Exception` or `Throwable` to crashlytics. But now lets take the following situation.

We have our custom logger, that also offers something like `SLog.e(String message)` and takes only a string message. Now we want to track all of these error logs as non fatals to crashlyics. I could create one `MyException` and record that error to crashlytics. But this has 2 major downsides:

1. The given message will not show up in the Firebase Crashlytics overview dashboard
2. If there are different error types with different messages, they will all grouped be together by Firebase

On iOS its trivial as the grouping is done via domain and errorCode, but on Android its just grouped by the filename and line.

**How can we conveniently track random errors to crashlytics without the boilerplate code of creating an exception class for each and every error log.**

Comment: Hey, did you manage to any solution?

Comment: I'm also struggling with this please if you find any solution please share it I will appreciate it! Thanks in advance!